# How can iPhone app play video uploaded by others in Facebook?

Tags: iphone, facebook, video

I want to play video in my own iPhone app, and the video's link is grabbed from the Video object returned by Graph API, as you know, it's the 'source' property. Can anyone tell me whether this is possible or not?

If it's possible, how to load video by using that source? There are two kinds of sources in Video object, one is on http://video.l3.fbcdn.net, and another is on http://video.ak.fbcdn.net. I try to visit those two links in PC browser, no one works, the result is that the former one returns a 401 error, and the latter one returns a 404 error.
If it's not, how can my app play a video uploaded by others on Facebook?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to a Facebook video, and NOT a video uploaded to another site and posted as a link on Facebook, the video referenced in the `source` attribute of a video post from `/posts` works for me, and appears to serve the video NOT using Flash, but some sort of QuickTime-friendly format (not sure exactly what the codec is).

However, I'm guessing you're concerned with videos that are posted as links from other sites that Facebook knows how to render in the Feed; for those, you'll need to figure out if those sites serve video in an QuickTime-friendly format and if so, how to get at that video rather than the Flash video.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show me one sample content of that 'source' in a video post? My problem is the 'source' property in a video object is not accessable. Two kinds of that source are: http://video.l3.fbcdn.net/cfs-l3-snc6/79166/252/1834450219708_55099.mp4?oh=51bd96a7a4cfe7f3966c7ec61f49d247&oe=4D957D00&l3s=20110330071136&l3e=20110401072136&lh=0e1828adc87fbb5ce8f5a and http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-ash4/81480/497/1953005544519_46961.mp4?oh=c5bf9e141580368330d48f8812b6f928&oe=4DA24200&__gda__=1302479360_995ff01b0d1f83c4b9db1e5f5fc3cd5e

Comment: And I think those 2 source links are all pointing to Facebook videos, not videos uploaded to another site and posted as a link on Facebook.

Comment: @olinYY: http://video.l3.fbcdn.net/cfs-l3-ash2/70113/778/10150292664920484_21630.mp4?oh=9b5696227242866fdfe582d15052dc18&oe=4DAE5300&l3s=20110418031904&l3e=20110420032904&lh=05cf0cf6d7b793e196a07. I think part of your issue might be user privacy/permissions; the videos I'm referencing were published by Pages, not profiles. You might try passing your access token as a parameter to that video URL and see if that helps you.

Comment: Yes, your link works, let me try to add access token on my link.

Comment: the source url works, and access token must be provided to get this url, thanks!